# Branch.io (deep link activity) not working on iOS12 swift?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, branch.io

We have implemented the deep link activity in our application. It worked in iOS 11. When we send SMS via a web portal. Its received in iPhone. **After updated into iOS 12** the link messages are not received for my iPhone devices. Here is my code below:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
    branch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController: true, deepLinkHandler: { params, error in
        if error == nil {}}

// Respond to URI scheme links
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    Branch.getInstance().handleDeepLink(url);
    return true
}
```

> we have added branch_app_domain, branch_key and URL Type in plist also.

Do we need to add anything in my code ??

Comment: You have to change in you info.plist file need add key and URL Types.

Comment: yes. I have added branch_app_domain, branch_key and  URL Type also

Comment: @HarikarthickK have you add association domain ?

Comment: yes. It was working in iOS11 but after updating the iOS12 i can't get any messages.

Comment: @HarikarthickK did you implement this method `func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?)` in your appdelegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After updating a device to iOS 11.2+,the app's AASA file is no longer downloaded reliably onto your user’s device after an app install. As a result, clicking on Universal Links will no longer open the app consistently. You can set [forced uri redirect mode](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#forced-redirections) on your Branch links to open the app with URI schemes. View details of the issue on the [Apple Bug report](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4999496467480576).

For any further questions, please write to integrations@branch.io.

Comment: Where can I change the uri_redirect_mode in branch dashboard?

Comment: @HarikarthickK Is your issue resolved? Did you find where we can change that uri_redirect_mode?