# Branch Deeplinking behaving differently on 2 different devices, same link

Tags: ios, branch.io

I've generated a branch link that my co-worker and I are both tapping on. When I tap it, I go straight to the app, to the correct screen. Boom, done.

When my co-worker (who built v1 of the app, so may have some old cached settings or something?) taps on the same link, he gets taken to a web page that asks "Open in BUMP *(our app)*)?" which then takes him to the right screen but does the push-to-that-screen behavior twice, seemingly once registering the action before the web interstitial and once after he confirms.

Every subsequent tap on the same link (or any branch link for him, for that matter) does the same behavior. Web link -> web -> app -> push 2x

Has anyone seen this before? Any idea how to remedy?

Comment: It must be either in your code, or in your Branch configuration. I'm betting on the first one.

Comment: We're running the same version of the app, tapping on the same link, fwiw

Comment: Are device model and especially OS version the same? Have you watched what's happening in the debugger?

Comment: same OS version, I'm on a 7, he's on an X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is an outstanding issue, introduced in iOS 11.2 and still persistent to today

> After updating a device to iOS 11.2+,the app's AASA file is no longer downloaded reliably onto your user’s device after an app install. As a result, clicking on Universal Links will no longer open the app consistently. [Source – StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001408/branch-io-deep-link-activity-not-working-on-ios12-swift)

Also from the Apple Radar:

> Sometimes, on any iOS 11.2+, the AASA file is not being updated after the application is installed. In that case, the only way to update it is to delete the app, restart the device, and install the app.
>   This was reproduced on multiple iPhone devices.
>
> Applications that were installed on the device before the update will continue working, however, upon reinstalling - they may stop working. [Radar – Apple](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4999496467480576)

Comment: what is the solution?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that on your device, you are being Universally Linked straight into your app as expected. Your co-worker should be seeing the same behavior if you guys are running the same exact build if your App.

As you've mentioned it could be that the AASA file did not download as it should have during the install. Can you have your coworker uninstall the app, restart device, and reinstall the app whilst monitoring Console logs as shown here:

https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#to-validate-if-aasa-file-successfully-downloaded

If he confirms that the AASA file is being downloaded but still not Universally Linking, please write into support@branch.io with your Branch AppID and we'll be glad to assist you with this issue. Thank you.